# RVIZ Application Not Launching

Tags: rviz, python2.7, python3, ubuntu, ubuntu-trusty

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Im trying to run an RVIZ application from the Udacity Robotics-Nanodegree but unfortunately when i try to run it it crashes with this message:

```
You can start planning now!

[ INFO] [1506666259.823327293]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ INFO] [1506666259.823388529]: OpenGl version: 4.5 (GLSL 4.5).
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Ogre::Exception'
  what():  OGRE EXCEPTION(5:): Could not find font Liberation Sans in MovableText::setFontName
[rviz_ML_Ubuntu_11752_4341152296783752344-4] process has died [pid 11776, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/rviz/rviz -d /home/ddomit/catkin_ws/src/RoboND-Kinematics-Project/kr210_claw_moveit/launch/moveit.rviz __name:=rviz_ML_Ubuntu_11752_4341152296783752344 __log:=/home/ddomit/.ros/log/c7f078f8-a4de-11e7-95b3-4ccc6acfcea6/rviz_ML_Ubuntu_11752_4341152296783752344-4.log].
log file: /home/ddomit/.ros/log/c7f078f8-a4de-11e7-95b3-4ccc6acfcea6/rviz_ML_Ubuntu_11752_4341152296783752344-4*.log
```

I can run RVIZ Perfectly without any application, but when I try to run this one it crashes. This is very weird because many other students have opened it without a problem, so its not application related.

I am Currently stuck in the program because of this problem. If anyone can help me it would be greaaatly appreciated!!!

Daniel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271834/rviz-application-not-launching/) by [ddomit](https://answers.ros.org/users/32091/ddomit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-09-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see #q271750 and [[notice] Removal of Arial in rviz caused breaking changes](https://discourse.ros.org/t/notice-removal-of-arial-in-rviz-caused-breaking-changes/2791).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0